# Firefox keyboard input stops working

Tags: windows-7, firefox, laptop, keyboard

All keyboard input stops working after a few minutes. Ctrl-T, ctrl-f, home, end, all have no effect, and I can't type into forms, the find bar or the location bar. If I switch tabs or programs using the mouse, the problem stops briefly, and resumes a few minutes later.

The same problem happens in safe mode. Reinstalling the keyboard driver didn't help.

Firefox 3.6.8, Windows 7, laptop keyboard.

Comment: What addons do you have installed in Firefox?

Comment: Adblock Plus, Automatic Save Folder, Download Statusbar, Downthemall, Easy DragToGo, Extended Copy Menu, Favicon Picker 3, FlashGot, Google Gears, Greasemonkey, Java Console, LogMeIn Remote Access Plugin, Menu Editor, Mouse Gestures Redox, NoScript, Organize Status Bar, Read It Later, Session Manager, Stylish, Tab Kit.

But the problem does still happen in safe mode, with extensions disabled.

Comment: Sadly, Firefox has a long history of keyboard issues. I had to stop using it a while ago because of one - [bug #249136](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=249136). That was eventually fixed, but I've just discovered a new one - [bug #530148](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=530148). There may be something seriously flawed in the core keyboard handling within Firefox. A quick search of the the Firefox bug list for 'keyboard'  shows 524 entries. Not that any of that is helpful to you, I just want to prepare you for the worst (as in: no solution). :-(

Comment: @boot13 I myself highly prefer firefox over others (specificly over Google Chrome) Firefox is Open Source, means that bugs get fixed quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem before on Firefox (way back on 3.5). I've come to believe that this is just caused by the fact that Firefox runs virtually like a VM interface-wise. Instead of using real OS widgets, it copies them and re-implements the look'n'feel using XUL (XML User interface Language). Supposedly this makes porting Firefox and its addons much easier. I wouldn't be surprised if they implemented keyboard hooks nonstandardly too, so when Firefox pauses, everything does.

What I suggest you do is either switch to another browser (simmer down, Firefox diehards), bear with it, or make Firefox itself faster using the standard ways (cache clearing, removing history, yadayada).

Comment: If Opera had any kind of support from Google (it doesn't - just try using anything Googlish in Opera) I would switch from Firefox in a heartbeat. It may be a little weird when you start using it, but it is a **great** browser.

Comment: Not exactly the answer I was looking for, but thanks anyway. I guess it's time to retry Opera and Chrome. What's funny is that I had to open up Firefox to answer this question, and Firefox wouldn't let me type this comment -- with only two tabs open! Curse your sudden and inevitable betrayal, Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Quick work-aroud:

1) Invoke Task Manager using Control Alt Delete simultaneously. This will "shortcut" some rogue processes, e.g. hanged macros, runaway addons, etc. This should give you back your keyboard system-wide (but not always in Firefox... more on this next). You can then simply exit Task Manager when its window has appeared. It only needs make one short appearance!

2) If problem persists: outside Firefox, clip some highlighted text, any text, e.g. from notepad (using Control-C) or from any file name field (using F2). Paste text into Firefox's URL or Search field (using Control-V). Press ENTER. Voilà!

If you use Autohotkey, you could even define a simple hotkey for this, as it seems to happen on average once a day...

Answer (score 0):

My keyboard is locked too only in Firefox. I was reading the avast scanning log and i saw some languagefiles that couldn't be read by it, so, i think that maybe they are some anti-virus progam may be locking this files.